# Magento 1: How to remove product name in Category page?

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, magento-1.9

I have a problem with removing the product name in category page for both of List and Grid view, I am using Magento 1.9.3.2 currently.

Could anybody help to advise which file should be modified if you know how to deal with this problem?
Thank you for your assistance in advance!

Comment: which theme are you using?

Comment: @BachchaSingh Hi Bachcha, thanks for your attention. I am using the default theme, and I think the file which should be modified may be app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/catalog/product/list.phtml , but I am not sure which part should be changed.

Comment: you need to remove all <h2 class="product-name">...</h2>, if not work can you please share link with me so i can help you.

Comment: @BachchaSingh Thank you, Bachcha. I work it out with your instruction, very very appreciate your valued help!!!

Comment: You can always take easy path and just use CSS `display:none` on product names ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code for get product name in list.phtml file

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>
```

So you need to remove the following code from list.phtml file

```
<h2 class="product-name">
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>">
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>
</a>
</h2>
```

**File Path:** `app/design/frontend/default/your-theme/template/catalog/product/‌​list.phtml`